# Check old password from database validation using jquery validate()

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying to check old password from database using jquery validation. its perfectlly work,
    but my problem is jQuery.validator.addMethod() check on keyup then process time is very slow because every time its called method.

My Code is:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
          /**Check old password */            
     jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkoldpassword",function(value,element,param){
                var old_pass = $("#old").val();
                var input_old_password = $("#old_password").val();
                var url = "{{url('admin/checkoldpassword')}}";
                var res = '';
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : url,
                    data : {old_pass , input_old_password },
                    async : false,
                    success : function(data) {
                        if(data == 'true') {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
               return res;
            },"Please enter correct old password value");

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
     validator = $("#changepassword_form").validate({
                    rules: {
                        new_password : {
                            required : true,
                            minlength : 8
                        },
                        confirm_password : {
                            required : true,
                            minlength : 8,
                            equalTo : "#new_password"
                        },
                        old_password : {
                            required : true,
                            checkoldpassword :true
                        }
                    },

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In controller

```
public function checkoldpassword(Request $request) 
        {
            $input = $request->all();
            if((\Hash::check($input['input_old_password'],$input['old_pass']))) {
                return 'true';
            }
            return 'false';
        }
```

Comment: You do a synchronous ajax request. Making it asynchronous would probably help a lot already.

Comment: You definitely don't want to use synchronous requests. They are terrible for UX as they freeze all rendering of the page until the request completes.

Comment: I have removed "async: false" then does not get a response in "res"variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use your ajax in to this doneTyping() funcion.

```
//setup before functions
    var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
    var doneTypingInterval = 5000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example
    var $input = $('#myInput');

    //on keyup, start the countdown
    $input.on('keyup', function () {
      clearTimeout(typingTimer);
      typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    });

    //on keydown, clear the countdown 
    $input.on('keydown', function () {
      clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    });

    //user is "finished typing," do something
    function doneTyping () {
      //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it in `.validate()` function,
like this:

```js
.validate({
   onkeyup: false,
});
```